# echo+htmlentities is not working propely?

Tags: php, echo, html-entities

I have this code:

```
$title = 'Alguém';
<h1><?php echo htmlentities($title, \ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); ?></h1>
```

PS: this is just a example, on my current code i get the value of `$title` from my database.

the result that can be seen on the web page:

```
<h1>Alguém</h1>
```

And the result that can be seen on the `view-source:`:

```
<h1>Algu&eacute;m</h1>
```

Why this happens? Am i using `htmlentities` correctly?

Comment: Your example code works fine. Seems like there is some issue with the tag missmatch in php file

Comment: When you say `view source` are you just saying that the source code for the html on your web page shows `<h1>Algu&eacute;m</h1>`?

Comment: @Joseph_J yes, the `view-source:https://example.com` should i worry about it?

Comment: @NishantSaini tag missmatch? what do you mean?

Comment: @Natalie Opening and closing php tags

Comment: Can you add the actual code so that we can pin point the issue.

Comment: @NishantSaini oh, no i'm sure that i don't have a tag missmatch. Actual code? on my actual code i just get the `$title` from db on a `select`, that's all. And it does not really matter, because you can reproduce the same "Error" with the code that i put on my question.

Comment: @Natalie No, your sample code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working correctly.  `htmlentities` converts html entities into a defined series of characters that your browser can interpret as the entity you want to display in your browser.  This is done to prevent malicious code from being run in your script.

As an example:

Without html entities being used this line of code will actually work.  Your browser sees the line of code as:

```
<script>alert("I just hacked your html")</script>
```

When you sanitize that same line of code with `htmlentities()` it replaces all of the entities with the defined series of character representations that the browser interprets as the entity. So this is what gets outputted to the browser.

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;I just hacked your html&quot;)&lt;
```

This script will not get ran as javascript in your browser.

Here is a link that you can read that will give you some additional information.  There is plenty of information on google that outlines this.

[html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp)

Here is a list of html entities:
[Entity list](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why `htmlentities()` would replace words with accents (áàéèâêã...etc)?

Comment: Because they are defined character representations  for those characters.  This is done out of necessity due to the different encoding options(character sets) that are used.  It's an attempt to standardize a wide variety of possible characters that might be used.  I would do some reading on it,  `htmlentities()` is doings it's job to help mitigate risk.

Comment: Food for thought:  A lot of people run `htmlentities()` or similar functions to thier data prior to moving the data to their database.  I recommend not running these functions prior to your database options.  If you properly use parameterized queries to query the database your raw data will sit in your database without issue.  Then all you have to do is make sure you sanitize your data after you  retrieve it from the database.  This can easily be done in the function that retrieves that data.  From that point on you don't have to worry about anything that is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

echo htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: There is no difference in the output between this and the OP code.